# Unable to print integer during program execution

Tags: python, list, printing, integer, msvcrt

I'm trying to enter a number into a list where each element has a single digit, and have the previously entered digit to display on the same line. Like this;

**Output**

```
Enter any 4-digit number
>1234
```

**Problem** is, in *real-time*, the program does not print the digit right after typing it in.

Only after the entire program has finished, It prints the whole list.

```
import msvcrt

digit = []

print("Enter any 4-digit number\n>", end = "")
for i in range(4):
    n = int(msvcrt.getch()) #input 1234
    digit.append(n)
    print(n, end = "")
```

**Edit**

```
print(n, end = "")
print(n, end = "", flush = True)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `input()` to get the number (and then split the digits afterwards)? It would give you feedback as you type each digit.

Comment: Try using `print(n, end="", flush=True)`

Comment: @Seb: `input()` doesn't return a value until the Enter key is pressed, is probably why.

Comment: @martineau: I'm not seeing anything in the code that would make it necessary to receive the values of the first digits before the number has been entered completely. I don't know if that is really important to OP's use case, hence my question.

Comment: @Seb: True—it's probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Are you using an IDE? IDEs usually implement custom console and IO that breaks getch.

Comment: @martineau Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using Atom. It's not causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding flush = True to last print() function.

```
print(n, end = "")
print(n, end = "", flush = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with this code:

```
digits = input()
if (len(digits) == 4 and digits.isdigit()):
    print(digits)
    listOfDigits = list(digits) # if you need the array for future use
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: no. If you want to print the input, it is better to print the input than print each var separately in the array.